# Robocopy - get filenames of copied files and add them to a list

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I am trying to copy specific files from recently created folders to my local disk and would I like to do is clean up the target directory by removing all the files except the ones that were copied using robocopy.

```
$source = "\\server\Builds\Installations\1.0"
$target = "\\c$\temp\Engineering\1.0"
$artifactsToMirror = "*.zip*"
$numberOfBuildsToMirror = 2
$doCleanUp = "true"
$filesToKeep = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

try
{   
    if (-Not (Test-Path -PathType Container $target))
    {
       Write-Output "Creating target directory..."
       New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $target
    }

    Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Where-Object { 
    ($_.GetFiles().Count -gt 0) } | Select-Object -Last $numberOfBuildsToMirror | ForEach-Object `
    {
        robocopy $source\$_ $target $artifactsToMirror /NJH /NJS /FP /NS /NC /NP /NDL /W:0 | ForEach-Object { $filesToKeep.Add($_)}
    }
    #Clean up target directory
    if ($doCleanUp -eq [bool]::TrueString -and $filesToKeep.Count -gt 0)
    {
       Write-Output "Cleaning up target directory"
       Remove-Item $target\* -recurse -exclude $filesToKeep -Force
    }   
}
catch [Exception]
{
   Write-Output "Not able to mirror the builds"
   Write-Output $_.Exception
   exit 1
}
```

Comment: Can you use the `/MIR` (Mirror) command with `robocopy`?

Comment: How do I do that? I only need specific files from the source.more specifically "*.zip" and "*.zip.sha256"

Comment: Or, can you simply delete all the files from the Target folder, before, you copy them?

Comment: I don't want the same zip to be copied again, they are about 7gb and the file copies from remote server are spotty, I would like to minimize unnecessary copies